# HTML table change text color on condition

Tags: html, css, google-sheets

I have a google app script in google sheets that pulls data and puts it into a table and emails it. It works great, but my question is, how do I change the text color to red if a table value, for example r[7], equals FAULT instead of Good?

```js
function sendEmail() {
  
  const ss  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet')//rename sheet name per your file;
  const headers = ws.getRange('A1:H1').getDisplayValues()//get table headers name;
  
  //assign variable to each header value
  const hospital = headers[0][0]; 
  const asset = headers[0][1];
  const time = headers[0][2];
  const helevel = headers[0][3];
  const hepressure = headers[0][4];
  const chillertemp = headers[0][5];
  const roomtemp = headers[0][6];
  const compressor = headers[0][7];

  const lr = ws.getRange('H14').getValues()//get last low row of active range, forula entered in B1 =countif(B3:B,"*")+2;

  const tablerangeValue = ws.getRange(2,1,18,9).getDisplayValues()//get range value, my data range start from 4th row and has 7 columns, pls chage per your need;

  const htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('emailTable');

  htmlTemplate.hospital = hospital;
  htmlTemplate.asset = asset;
  htmlTemplate.time = time;
  htmlTemplate.helevel = helevel;
  htmlTemplate.hepressure = hepressure;
  htmlTemplate.chillertemp = chillertemp;
  htmlTemplate.roomtemp = roomtemp;
  htmlTemplate.compressor = compressor;
  htmlTemplate.tablerangeValue = tablerangeValue;

  const htmlForEmail = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();
  
  
  var toEmail = 'user@email.com';
  var ccEmail = '';

  MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: toEmail,
  //cc: ccEmail,
  subject: "***Daily Readings***",
  htmlBody:htmlForEmail
    });

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
  table, th, td {
  border: 0px solid black;
  font-size:15px;
}

th, thead {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

</style>  
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <table id="table1">
        <thead>
          <th><?= hospital ?></th><th><?= asset ?></th><th><?= time ?></th><th><?= helevel ?></th><th><?= hepressure ?></th><th><?= chillertemp ?></th><th><?= roomtemp ?></th><th><?= compressor ?></th>
        </thead>
        <tbody >
          <? tablerangeValue.forEach(r => {?>
          <tr> 
          <td><?= r[0] ?></td><td><?= r[1] ?></td><td><?= r[2] ?></td><td style="text-align:center"><?= r[3] ?></td><td style="text-align:center"><?= r[4] ?></td><td style="text-align:center"><?= r[5] ?></td><td style="text-align:center"><?= r[6] ?></td><td style="text-align:center" ><?= r[7] ?></td>
          </tr>
          <?})?>
          
        </tbody>

      </table>
      <script> 
       const values = document.querySelectorAll("td");

function changeTdColor() {
  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) { // iterate all thorugh td
      if (values[i].innerText == "r[9]") { // check if td has desired value
          values[i].style.backgroundColor = "red"; // if matches, change color
          }
       }
}

changeTdColor(); // call function
      </script>
      
    </div>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

I have added the other part of code that pulls the data from the google sheet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript.

For example you can iterate all `td` and check values.

```js
const values = document.querySelectorAll("td");

function changeTdColor() {
  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) { // iterate all thorugh td
      if (values[i].innerText == "r[9]") { // check if td has desired value
          values[i].style.backgroundColor = "red"; // if matches, change color
          }
       }
}

changeTdColor(); // call function
```

```html
<table id="table1">
      <tr> 
        <td>r[0]</td>
        <td>r[1]</td>
        <td>r[2]</td>
        <td>r[9]</td>
        <td>r[4]</td>
        <td>r[9]</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Where would I put this in my html code? Do I use the <script> tag?

Comment: Yes, you can use script tag. But be sure your script tag is end of the your body. 
Also do not forget to upvode and accept solution if this is helpful

Comment: This did not work, I edited my code. Can you see if I did it correctly?

Comment: Ok @Lane, I tested my code (second Answer below) in xampp and as a PHP file and its working correctly. Just copy and paste. If it works for you, please kindly accept my answer thank you very much.

Comment: @Ezani, this still does not work. I am adding the other part of my code to see if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>

  <head>
  
    <base target="_top">
    
    
    <style>
      table, th, td {
      border: 0px solid black;
      font-size:15px;
      }

      th, thead {
        background-color: lightblue;
      }

</style>  

  </head>
  
  
  <body>
  
    <div>
    
    <?php define("r",["Good", "FAULT", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Good"]); ?>
    
      <table id="table1">
      
          <tr> 
          <td><?php if (r[0]=="FAULT") { echo "<td style='color:red'>" . r[0] . "</td>"; } else { echo "<td style='color:black'>" . r[0] . "</td>"; } ?></td>
          <td><?php if (r[1]=="FAULT") { echo "<td style='color:red'>" . r[1] . "</td>"; } else { echo "<td style='color:black'>" . r[1] . "</td>"; } ?></td>
          <td><?php if (r[2]=="FAULT") { echo "<td style='color:red'>" . r[2] . "</td>"; } else { echo "<td style='color:black'>" . r[2] . "</td>"; } ?></td>
          <td><?php if (r[3]=="FAULT") { echo "<td style='color:red'>" . r[3] . "</td>"; } else { echo "<td style='color:black'>" . r[3] . "</td>"; } ?></td>
          <td><?php if (r[4]=="FAULT") { echo "<td style='color:red'>" . r[4] . "</td>"; } else { echo "<td style='color:black'>" . r[4] . "</td>"; } ?></td>
          <td><?php if (r[5]=="FAULT") { echo "<td style='color:red'>" . r[5] . "</td>"; } else { echo "<td style='color:black'>" . r[5] . "</td>"; } ?></td>
          <td><?php if (r[6]=="FAULT") { echo "<td style='color:red'>" . r[6] . "</td>"; } else { echo "<td style='color:black'>" . r[6] . "</td>"; } ?></td>
          <td><?php if (r[7]=="FAULT") { echo "<td style='color:red'>" . r[7] . "</td>"; } else { echo "<td style='color:black'>" . r[7] . "</td>"; } ?></td>
          </tr>
        
      </table>
      
    </div>
    
  </body>
  
  </html>
```

Comment: OP asks changing colors in a spesific tables.

Comment: Ok thank you @Muhammedogz. Answer edited.

Comment: I need to change the font color only when the cell reads fault, all other output should remain default.